# Generic collection dependency in java spring

Tags: java, spring

Given the following code (using spring 3.2.5):

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyClass myClass(@Qualifier("messageFeeders") List<MessageFeeder> messageFeeders) {
        return new MyClass(messageFeeders);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageFeederSubclassOne messageFeeder1() {
        return new MessageFeederSubclassOne();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageFeederSubclassTwo messageFeeder2() {
        return new MessageFeederSubclassTwo();
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("messageFeeders")
    public List<MessageFeeder> messageFeeders(MessageFeederSubclassOne messageFeeder1, MessageFeederSubclassTwo messageFeeder2) {
        return ImmutableList.of(messageFeeder1, messageFeeder2);
    }
}
```

I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myClass' defined in class path resource [com/company/configuration/MyConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.util.List]: : No qualifying bean of type [com.company.messagebroker.MessageFeeder] found for dependency [collection of com.company.messagebroker.MessageFeeder]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=messageFeeders)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:738)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.company.messagebroker.MessageFeeder] found for dependency [collection of com.company.messagebroker.MessageFeeder]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=messageFeeders)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:816)
```

Now, I realize that spring is attempting to find beans of type MessageFeeder and stuff them all in this list, but my hope was that the qualifier will force it to actually inject the list I defined myself.

Looking at the DefaultListableBeanFactory code, it seems to completely disregard the qualifier.

Also, why does it fail? Even disregarding the qualifier, shouldn't it detect the two beans that inherit from MessageFeeder and use them?

I would prefer not to change the messageFeeders bean, as I'm not the only one using it. Is there any simple way to make Spring take the qualifier into consideration?

Comment: its clear from stacktrace you have problem in `MyClass`do you even have constructor with list argument?

Comment: Of course it does. Otherwise this wouldn't event compile. You misunderstood the error. It's not referring to MyClass at all, the problem is in satisfying the dependencies of the bean you can see defined in the code above....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
@Qualifier("messageFeeders")`
public MyClass myClass(List<MessageFeeder> messageFeeders) 
{
    return new MyClass(messageFeeders);`
}
```

Explanation:

I first tried to do it on Spring version 4.3.2 and it worked just fine the way you defined it. However, I changed my Spring dependencies to version 3.2.5 and I received your exception.

The `@Autowired` is the proper way to inject beans by annotations, and it does that by type. The IOC container injects the beans by type recognition in case of `@Autowired` annotation.

Now, what if we have more than one bean of the same type in our IOC container? how will it know which bean to inject?

Simply, by the `@Qualifier` annotation.

But you still need to use the `@Autowired` annotation with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `@Resource` as it might solve the problem

```
@Bean
@Resource(name = "messageFeeders") 
public MyClass myClass(List<MessageFeeder> messageFeeders) {
    return new MyClass(messageFeeders);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean javax.annotation.Resource? if so, it seems that it can't be applied to parameters. Also, it should be @Resource(name = "messageFeeders")

Answer (score 0):

Create a new wrapper class for the list of message feeders, change the bean creation to use the new class and then add '@Autowired' to your constructor call

```
class MessageFeederList extends ArrayList<MessageFeeder>{}

@Bean
public MessageFeederList messageFeeders(
    MessageFeederSubclassOne messageFeeder1, 
    MessageFeederSubclassTwo messageFeeder2){
    return ImmutableList.of(messageFeeder1, messageFeeder2);
}

@Bean
public MyClass myClass(@Autowired MessageFeederList messageFeeders) {
    return new MyClass(messageFeeders);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I realize this solution will work, but as I said I would like not to change the messageFeeders bean, as it would require changing a lot of places that do manage to use it (by directly calling context.getBean("messageFeeders")).
In this case it's simpler to just manually inject the two subclasses to the MyClass bean